# Search Firebase Database using key with search bar

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, search, indexing

[image]

I have data in firebase database and the data is structured as shown in the attached image. I am trying to search using search bar to look for the name of recipe(s) when user enter search query in the app. Indexing rules currently set also shown in the attached image. Here is my code:

```
self.findRecipes(text: "Lemon")

func findRecipes(text: String)->Void{

    ref.child("Categories").queryOrdered(byChild: "recipeName").queryStarting(atValue: text).queryEnding(atValue: text+"\u{f8ff}").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot)

    })
}
```

The output in the console is

```
Snap (Categories) <null>
```

Any help?

Comment: You're missing a level. the *recipeName* node is not a child of a child of  /Categories/. It's  a child of the child nodes within */Categories/Beverages/* so you need to add */Beverages/* (or /Breakfast & Brunch) to the ref path to query. If you need to perform shallower queries, consider keeping all of the nodes withing the parent Categories node and add a child node that defines what kind it is */Categories/childByAutoId/recipeName: "xxxx"* and another child */recipeType: "Beverage"*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I only know how to retrieve data successfully using search bar from firestore DB in webapps. May be it can help you.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search" id="latestHotDogStatus"> 
<ul id="pastComments2"></ul>
<li><id="loadButton">Search</li>
```

JS:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var firestore = firebase.firestore();
var docRef = firestore.collection("indian");
var showat2 = document.querySelector("#pastComments2");
var loadbutton = document.querySelector("#loadButton");
var inputTextField = document.querySelector("#latestHotDogStatus");
loadbutton.addEventListener("click",function(){
    docRef.get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const myData = doc.data();
                        if(myData.dname == inputTextField.value){

               showat2.innerHTML += myData.dname+" "+myData.dno+myData.no+ ;  
                  inputTextField.innerHTML = " ";
        }                  

      });
    }).catch(function(error){
    console.log("error: "+error);
  });
});
```